# When both http requests done execute function

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, angularjs

I'm currently learning *Javascript* and *AngularJS* in specific and there's one thing I can't seem to understand how to do. As you'll see futher, I'm also struggling to switch my mind from "sequential" thinking.
I want to make two `$http.post()` requests and when both of them are successed execute a function. I managed to make it working by nesting requests like that:

```
$http.post(url, {something}).success(function (response) {
    $http.post(url, {something}).success(function (secondResponse) {
      myFunction();
    });
});
```

That's working, but that's nested, not async and generally lame. I wonder if that's possible to make these requests like that (I know that following code will not work properly):

```
$http.post(url, {something}).success(function (response) { someKindOfFlag = true });    
$http.post(url, {something}).success(function (response) { anotherKindOfFlag = true });
if (someKindOfFlag && anotherKindOfFlag) { myFunction(); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have heard of $q or promises in Javascript in general and Angular in particular. In order to achieve what you wish to do, you need to use the $q API.

Here is how you do it. You will need to inject $q into your service or your controller ( But, I would suggest that this go into a service if possible! ).

```
var firstResponse = $http.post(url, {something});

var secondResponse = $http.post(url, {something});

$q.all([firstResponse,secondResponse]).then(function(data){
      //data[0] === firstResponseData
      //data[1] === secondResponseData 
      myFunction();
});
```

Comment: I've heard of the term promise in _JS_, but never really got to it as much as I wanted. Thanks, your solution works exactly like I want and I promise I'll research about promises more :)

Comment: @the_lay you are welcome. The firt time I "got" promises I was overwhelmed. Hope its the same for you as well :).

Answer (score 2):

The proper solution in this case is to relay on the promise API and use [AngularJS $q service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q) - its `$q.all()` method to be more precise.

The $http service already works with promises, in the sense that it returns a promise from $http function calls.

To have a callback executed when both `$http` requests have completed you could use the `$q.all()` method in the following way:

```
$q.all([$http.post(url, {something}), $http.post(url, {something})]).then(function(arrayOfResponses) {
  // success callback code goes here
});
```

Comment: I can't upvote yet, so all I can do is just say thank you! :)